# Understand how sorting with compare works for an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I want to understand how the following comparator gives me results in ascending order:

```
Comparator<Integer> ints = (i1, i2) -> i1 - i2;
```

How does providing `i1-i2` as the implementation give me results in ascending order?
Can you please explain in the context of the ArrayList with elements [5, 4, 1, 2]? I am looking for some explanation similar to this: first 1 is compared with 4, the result is 4-1=3, which is a positive number, the current state of arraylist becomes this [4, 5, 1, 2] and so on to get to the final result of [1, 2, 4, 5].

I want to understand the working of the comparator implementation.

Comment: Note that, for sufficiently large values, this implementation is vulnerable to integer overflow/underflow, leading to incorrect comparisons. It's better to just use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` or `Integer::compare`. That said, [Shila's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76994393/6395627) gives an excellent explanation regarding how this _comparator's_ implementation works (though the _sorting algorithm_ used by the `sort` implementation may be different; regardless, the comparator is algorithm-agnostic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to understand how the sorting algorithm uses the comparator internally. So, let's see how `Collections.sort()` uses Comparator` to sort a list.

Let's peek into the JDK  and see specifically how insertion sort uses comparator.

This is the JDK code snippet for insertion sort which `Collections.sort()` uses to sort list with `size < 7`.

```
for (int i=low; i<high; i++){
    for (int j=i; j>low && c.compare(dest[j-1], dest[j])>0; j--)
        swap(dest, j, j-1);
    }

   //remaining logic
}
```

We can see that the sorting algorithm uses the `c.compare()` method to decide the sorting order.

Suppose this is my comparator function:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
   @Override
   public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
       return x - y;
   }
}
```

The sorting algorithm will calculate `c.compare(dest[j-1], dest[j]) > 0` for every element. And, it will only swap the left and right value if the above expression is greater than 0. i.e. if `x > y` OR `dest[j-1]` > `dest[j]`.

Thus, after swapping the `smaller element in the right comes to left and greater element goes to right side` which is basically sorting the list in ascending order.

If, we do `y-x` in `compare()` method, sorting in reverse order(descending order) will occur using similar logic.

Comment: This answer was very helpful in understanding more about the internal details of the comparator and precisely answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped @AnishGhimire. Could you please accept it as the answer?  It would be helpful for fellow learners to spot the most relevant answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Comparator's comparison function defines the ordering of two elements. Let's understand how the subtraction works in terms of comparison:
If you have:

1. `i1 > i2`, then (`i1 - i2`) is a positive number.
2. `i1 < i2`, then `i1 - i2` is a negative number.
3. `i1 == i2`, then `i1 - i2` is zero.

   The result of the Comparator's `compare` function:

   - A negative value means the first argument is less than the second.
   - A positive value means the first argument is greater than the second.
   - Zero means the arguments are equal.

   Given the list [5, 4, 1, 2] and the comparator `ints = (i1, i2) -> i1 - i2`, let's see step-by-step:

   1. Comparing 5 and 4:

      - 5 - 4 = 1 (a positive number)
      - This means 5 > 4, so 5 should come after 4 in the list.
      - The list becomes [4, 5, 1, 2].
   2. Comparing 5 and 1:

      - 5 - 1 = 4 (a positive number)
      - This means 5 > 1, so 5 should come after 1.
      - The list becomes [4, 1, 5, 2].
   3. Comparing 5 and 2:

      - 5 - 2 = 3 (a positive number)
      - This means 5 > 2, so 5 should come after 2.
      - The list becomes [4, 1, 2, 5].
   4. Comparing 4 and 1:

      - 4 - 1 = 3 (a positive number)
      - This means 4 > 1, so 4 should come after 1.
      - The list becomes [1, 4, 2, 5].
   5. Comparing 4 and 2:

      - 4 - 2 = 2 (a positive number)
      - This means 4 > 2, so 4 should come after 2.
      - The list becomes [1, 2, 4, 5].

At this point, the list is sorted in ascending order, so the comparisons stop.

The above steps assume a simple bubble sort for illustration purposes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class comparing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize ArrayList
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(4);
        numbers.add(1);
        numbers.add(2);
        // Print the original list
        System.out.println("\t\t Original list: " + numbers);
        // Custom comparator
        Comparator<Integer> ints = (i1, i2) -> i1 - i2;
        // Sort using the comparator
        numbers.sort(ints);
        // Print the sorted list
        System.out.println("\t\t Sorted list: " + numbers);
    }

}
```

the result would be:
[image]

PS. In the case of ArrayList.sort(), the underlying implementation uses TimSort (a hybrid of MergeSort and InsertionSort)and it doesn't sort by repeatedly comparing and swapping adjacent pairs like the example.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Good Answer. Even better would be a mention of  the dangers of integer overflow, and a suggestion in real work to use solutions like `Comparator.naturalOrder()` or `Integer::compare` as mentioned [by Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76994136/understand-how-sorting-with-compare-works-for-an-arraylist-in-java#comment135731672_76994136).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a 6th step comparing 1 and 2? They happen to be in the right order in this case, but there's nothing guaranteeing that.

Comment: The ArrayList.sort() method doesn't sort by repeatedly comparing and swapping adjacent pairs like the example you provided. That would be a basic idea behind the Bubble Sort algorithm, which is not what Java's ArrayList.sort() uses.

Your step-by-step process only swaps pairs, but TimSort breaks down the list into smaller chunks, sorts those, and then merges them back together. Thus, there will be numerous comparisons that happen beyond the simple adjacent pairs.

You're right that there would be a comparison between 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Shila. It's more clear to me now.

Comment: @AnishGhimire I would appreciate if you consider my answer as the accepted answer to your question in case it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong: your phrase "first 1 is compared with 4 (and so on)" describes a sorting algorithm but a `Comparator` is not aware of any sorting algorithm.  The idea behind a `Comparator` is that **any** sorting algorithm will need to compare pairs of items, so the `Comparator` provides this specific ability to any sorting algorithm, including the one implemented by [`ArrayList.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) (whatever it is). Future versions of Java may implement a new, better, not-yet-invented algorithm, and the `Comparator` you provide will still be valid and necessary.